# Meteor stuck at update to 1.3

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite

I have created apps on Meteor 1.2.x. But, now Meteor 1.3 is released.
and as I was running meteor command in command prompt then it told me to update your meteor version to 1.3.4.

One I used meteor update command, it started downloading the update. But as progress bar filled it disappeared, but downloading still continuing.

I had kept it from 1 to 2 hours but downloading was never completed. I also tried reinstalling 1.3 fresh. After this I tried to run meteor command in the same app as above, but it still behave the same way. again I kept it form 1 to 2 hours but download never completed.

What am i suppose to do now? I'm stuck.

I've attached an image.
[windows 10 cmd.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmTNV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart the process a few times, their server is really annoying. I couldn't make it work for hours, and then somehow it worked.

Wait until you see the %99-100 in the progressbar